# Optimization Word Problem

Tags: calculus

A farmer is building a new cylindrical silo with a flat roof and an earthen floor that will hold $20,000 m^3$ of corn. What dimensions should the farmer construct his silo if he wants to use the least material for
construction?

I believe I have to use the surface area and area equations. Can anybody lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
V&=20000\\
\pi r^2h&=20000\\
h&=\frac{20000}{\pi r^2}\\
A&=2\pi rh+\pi r^2\\
A&=2\pi r\frac{20000}{\pi r^2}+\pi r^2\\
A(r)&=\frac{40000}{ r}+\pi r^2\\
\end{align}
What do you do to optimize this function?

Comment: Thanks, all I have to do now is to find the derivative. Thanks for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You have $V = \pi r^2 l = 20,000$ and $A = 2\pi r h + \pi r^2$ as the volume and surface area, respectively. You can eliminate one of the variables using the first equation, plug it into the second, and minimize A.

Answer (score 0):

If our silo has radius $r$ and height $h$, then the volume and surface-area are given by
$$
V = \pi r^2 h\\
A = 2\pi r h + \pi r^2
$$ 
Note that $2\pi r h$ is the surface-area of the walls, and $\pi r^2$ is the surface-area of the roof.
Now, if we want to find the radius that minimizes surface area, we note that $V = 20,000$ and solve for $h$ to get
$$
h = \frac{20,000}{\pi r^2}
$$
Which means that we need to find the $r$ that minimizes
$$
A(r) = 2\pi r \cdot \frac{20,000}{\pi r^2} + \pi r^2
$$